# Where is this function getRowTaxDisplayPrecision() written?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have checked all over the place, but couldn't locate `getRowTaxDisplayPrecision()` function. This is referenced in following function:

```
class  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Abstract

/**
     * Retrieve price attribute html content
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @param bool $strong
     * @param string $separator
     * @return string
     */
    public function displayPriceAttribute($code, $strong = false, $separator = '<br />')
    {
        if ($code == 'tax_amount' && $this->getOrder()->getRowTaxDisplayPrecision()) {
            return $this->displayRoundedPrices(
                $this->getPriceDataObject()->getData('base_'.$code),
                $this->getPriceDataObject()->getData($code),
                $this->getOrder()->getRowTaxDisplayPrecision(),
                $strong,
                $separator
            );
        } else {
            return $this->displayPrices(
                $this->getPriceDataObject()->getData('base_'.$code),
                $this->getPriceDataObject()->getData($code),
                $strong,
                $separator
            );
        }
    }
```

If the function is not defined then why it doesn't throw any error?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Magento makes use of magic getters and setters.

The call you are refering to is most likely a property of the order object, not a method. It would most likely return NULL if not set anywhere.

What is interesting is that a search through the entire codebase does not reveal any occuranc of

setRowTaxDisplayPrecision or even row_tax_display_precision

is this maybe defunct code/getter/method call from a past versions?